# Test Microsoft Powerpoint 2007 compatibility on Mac

Tags: macos, compatibility, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I've made a slide using MS Powerpoint, but the slide is going to play on a Mac and I don't have a Mac. Is there any way to test whether my slides of Powerpoint is compatible on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility is not 100% between PowerPoint 2007 and PowerPoint 2008 (for Mac)

To be absolutely sure your layout stays intact I would recommend exporting your slides as a PDF and using the slideshow feature to play them on the Mac (you can't have animations or effects that way though)

Comment: forgot to mention, I tried to save the pptx file as a .pdf, but powerpoint report an error message, and could export the slide as a pdf file.